# xing / wysihtml5 unescapes &lt; and &gt;

Tags: javascript, wysihtml5

I'm trying to use xing/wysihtml5 to edit blog entries in my backend.
Some of the entries contain code examples, with PHP, HTML and JavaScript.
In the database all < and > inside of pre/code are written as &lt; and &gt;
But as soon as I load the record into wysihtml5 the &lt; and &gt; get replaced with < and >

Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">something to do here()</script>
```

If &lt; and &gt; it get replaced I get a blank line within the editor.
I didn't find any hints, where this gets replaced.

**Edit**

If I replace &lt; with &amp;lt; in database it gets replaced with &lt; in editor and I can work with it, but this cripples the frontend rendering:

```
&:lt;script type="text/javascript"&gt;something to do here()&lt;/script&gt;
```

Well, I could do a search and replace before loading to editor and before writting back to database, but this would be crap.

Comment: "as soon as I load the record into wysihtml5" — How are you doing that?

Comment: With ColdFusion I do:
<textarea>#query.column#</textarea>

Comment: You have to escape that data _before_ you place it into the textarea.

Comment: Ok, it's not an issue with wysihtml5, but with textarea in general.